# Sessions across all subdomains

Tags: session, subdomain

I am hoping some of you might have some answers here. I've been at this for many hours and I'm not making much headway. From doing an extensive amount of research, I see this is a common problem without many solutions.

I have my login at domain.com that then goes to the user profile at domain.com/profile?u=username that has been rewritten with .htaccess to username.domain.com. I need to have access to SESSION username across all subdomains so I can see if the user is on their own profile or not. I have tried all the basic solutions to get SESSIONS working across all subdomains with .htaccess etc (I do not have direct access to php.ini), but nothing seemed to work; with the exception of `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');` at the top of the script setting the SESSION. This all of a sudden worked - but the problem is - it also all of a sudden stopped working and has intermittently continued to work and not work without me touching the code.

My questions here are...

1. Does anyone have any idea why this would be intermittently working and then not working?
2. Does anyone have any other simple, cross platform solutions to solve this problem.
3. Failing that, I believe I can store the SESSION in the database and recreate it in all the subdomains. This seems inefficient, but might be the only solution. What are your thoughts and what would be the best way to do this?

I would really appreciate any help in this. This has proven a real challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by simply adding a text file to my main directory called php.ini with `session.cookie_domain = ".domain.com"` inside. That was it. And you have to re-launch your browser.